# conversion date from string bring wrong value

Tags: java, date, datetime, type-conversion

I'm using the following conversion from string to date

```
    String attr = "2013-09-11"
Date date = null;
SimpleDateFormat parsedDate = null;

parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

try {
date = parsedDate.parse(attr);
} catch (ParseException e) {

}
```

Now the date have value **Fri Jan 11 00:09:00 IST 2013** 
why is that? and how can I change it to bring appropriate value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mm` is for minutes, you're looking for `MM` for months.

```
parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

More info: [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), in the **Date and Time Patterns** and **Examples** section .